# Limite de emails recebidos a partir do mesmo domínio

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer, spam

Existem políticas de verificação de fontes de SPAM que se baseiam na quantidade de emails que determinado domínio está a enviar por hora.

Tais políticas podem ser internas como por exemplo as aplicadas pela Google, ou gerais como é o exemplo das listas de SPAM.

Quando falamos em otimizar o envio de newsletters a partir duma solução própria as primeiras preocupações são não baixar a reputação do IP de envio nem ficar com esse mesmo IP presente nas listas de SPAM mais comuns.

#### Ao analisar isto, surgiu uma pergunta:

> Nos dias de hoje, qual o limite que empresas como a [Google](http://www.gmail.com/), [Microsoft](http://www.outlook.com/), [Yahoo](https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=http://mail.yahoo.com) e outros aplicam para discernir se o envio é uma newsletter fidedigna ou uma fonte de SPAM?

Claro, existem centenas de métodos em uso para se apurar o que é SPAM e o que não é, mas o que se pretende tratar neste tópico é o limite de emails seja por minuto, hora ou dia, cujo mesmo não podemos ultrapassar de forma a garantir que por exemplo a Google não vai considerar determinado endereço uma fonte de SPAM quando o mesmo está apenas a enviar newsletters fidedignas!

**Surge então a necessidade de saber:**

```
┌─────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┐
│  Controlado em  │  Tipo               │  Limite por?  │  Limite de?  │
├─────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┤
│  Google         |  Provedor de Email  │  Hora         │  100         │
├─────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┤
|  Microsoft      |  Provedor de Email  │  Dia          │  100000      │
├─────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┤
|  Spamhaus       │  Lista de SPAM      │  Dia          │  1000000000  │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘
```

No seguimento de tentar obter estes valores ou uma linha de referência para planear a aplicação de forma eficiente surgiu esta informação:

[Google Apps - Receiving limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366776?hl=en) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

> ...
> If an account reaches the limit, a user cannot receive any new email ...
>
> ```
> ┌─────────────┬──────────┐
> │ Per minute  │  180     │
> ├─────────────┼──────────┤
> │ Per hour    │  3600    │ 
> ├─────────────┼──────────┤
> │ Per day     │  86,400  │ 
> └─────────────┴──────────┘
> ```

Mas este limite é para as contas de Apps, e para o Gmail? E nos outros? Estará a ser levantada uma tempestade num copo de água?

Comment: Favoritei sua pergunta, interessante... Não é uma tempestade em copo d'água não, mas a política se aplica por serviço ou empresa, geralmente existe um padrão, mas as particularidades existem de empresa para empresa. Sugiro você entrar em contato com o suporte do Google, neste caso, e entender os detalhes sobre as políticas de SPAM. Deixo um link aqui sobre esta política do Gmail: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178266?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 1):

Os limites citados são para o google apps, mas provavelmente se aplicam also ao gmail.

No entanto, esses são limites **de recebimento e por conta**, que não te interessam, a menos que você esteja pretendendo encher completamente o inbox do usuário com a sua newsletter, o que pra mim é spam.

O que te interessaria são **limites de envio por IP**, quantos emails similares pra contas diferentes o gmail aceitaria antes de marcar o seu IP como spammer.

Essa informação não é publica e na realidade o gmail (e nenhum ESP que se preze) não deve usar tal técnica pois tudo o que um spammer teria que fazer pra evitar o filtro seria limitar o numero de spams enviado a certo dominio por dia.

O que você precisa fazer pra garantir que seu email não seja considerado spam é cuidar da reputação do seu IP, que é um processo complicado... Algumas dicas pra te colocar na direção correta:

- Certifique-se que o seu IP e outros IPs na vizinhança não foram utilizados previamente por spammers. Começar já com má reputação é horrível. Verifique nos sites de listas, como spamhaus e sorbs. Use o mxtoolbox pra ver se o seu IP não esta listado no momento, e faça isso periodicamente. Ah, obviamente seu IP deve ser **fixo**.
- Tenha certeza que as suas newsletters incluem um 'one click unsubscribe' link. E que usuários que clicam nele não precisam fazer login pra se remover de sua lista e não receberão mais suas newsletters.
- Use um processo de inscrição duplo (double opt-in), o cadastro só é confirmado quando o usuário clica no link no email de confirmação.
- Tenha certeza que o hostname do seu MTA tem um A record e que a resolução reversa é válida.  Hostname -> A -> Hostname
- Tenha certeza que o seu MTA não pode ser usado como um 'open relay'.
- Use as ferramentas do MXtoolbox pra ver se há outras coisas a corrigir no seu DNS.
- Peça aos seus usuários pra adicioná-lo a lista de endereços.

Quando essas coisas estiverem funcionando corretamente, investigue:

- DKIM
- SPF
- Feedback Loops
- List-Unsubscribe header

O mais importante é ter certeza que quem está recebendo sua newsletter quer recebê-la, consegue se remover da lista quando quiser e que o seu conteúdo é relevante.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que partindo do princípio que o google oferece uma e-mail gratuito pra o usuário final, bem como hotmail, não há como atingir as caixas postais desses usuários, nesses serviços, com eficiência, sem um acordo financeiro, partindo de um único IP. 
Minha dica seria que, em caso de mail marketing, você configura-se um grande range de MX, e de preferência em vários domínios. 
Agradeço palas métricas já obtidas e disponibilizadas!